# Can I use the spiritual weapon spell so it can take the form of a legendary weapon and gain it's effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

In dnd, I'm planning on playing a fighter/sorcerer with divine soul (giving me access to cleric spells) and battle master, essentially having the ability to be the active person in the group (I call it the "holy errand boy") however, during theory crafting I found legendary weapons and figured "if I can take the form of any weapon and it's effects if it's associated with a deity, then what about weapons like Defender which is stupid versatile or Luck Blade which according to CBR is the best weapon in the game apparently?" I'd love the ability to conjure Luck Blade and have access to wish for about 60 seconds and get the real thing, but that seems incredibly overpowered and WAY too good to be true. Is it?

Comment: I’ve added the dnd-5e tag since this looks like a 5e question. Is that correct?

Comment: yea thanks for the clarification btw

Answer (score 9):

#### The spell does what the description says it does.

The spell description tells you exactly what the effect of the spell is. The rules for Spellcasting state:

> Each spell description in Chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell’s name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. *The rest of a spell entry describes the spell’s effect.*

*Spiritual weapon* tells you what it can do, and what it can do is create a weapon that *resembles* a certain weapon:

> The weapon can take whatever form you choose. Clerics of deities who are associated with a particular weapon (as St. Cuthbert is known for his mace and Thor for his hammer) make *this spell's effect resemble that weapon.*

It can *resemble* a particular weapon, but only has the effect of the spell, not any affects the real version of the weapon may have.

And for a bit of general guidance, if your reading of a 2nd level spell (*spiritual weapon*) allows you to recreate the effect of a 9th level spell (*wish*), that should give a strong indication that you’ve misunderstood something

Comment: So spiritual weapon can make a replica of a another weapon? Damn that sucks.

Comment: @egg Spiritual weapon is a fantastic spell. I don’t understand why you would be so disappointed that a 2nd level spell is not as strong as a 9th level spell. That’s like buying a car and being upset it can’t fly to Mars.

Comment: Because luck blade, also I'm not complaining seeing as though it has access to inflict wounds and it has a lot of staying power because the **at higher levels** thing.